# Transformer saturation value in volt-seconds

Tags: transformer, saturation

I have a slight confusion regarding the saturation rating of transformers. I often find this value stated in Volt-Seconds, which is a unit for the saturation *flux*, i.e. the maximum flux that the *core* can hold. After all, the saturation flux density \$B_\text{sat}\$ and the cross section of the core \$A\$ are both independent of its windings. So their product \$\Phi_\text{sat}=B_\text{sat}\cdot A\$, which happens to have units of Volt-Seconds, has to be independent of the windings, too.

Therefore, I regarded the saturation Volt-Second rating to be a *property of the transformer core*.

But then I thought about what happens in a 2:1 transformer when I apply the same Vs to one or the other winding (with no load on the second winding):

- The inductance of the shorter winding is 1/4th of the inductance of the longer winding
- So the current through the shorter winding will rise 4x as fast
- So for the same Vs applied to each winding, the shorter winding will have developed *twice* as many Ampere-Turns
- So the shorter winding would have generated twice the flux for the same Vs (and would thus saturate at a lower Volt-Second rating)

Now I was confused, because the latter consideration would indicate that the Volt-Second saturation does in fact depend on the winding properties and *is not* a property of the core.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: For a voltage transformer, the current does not matter. You can have very low magnetization current and still be able to saturate it. For a 50/60 Hz one, it's just Urms = 4.44fNAB where B is your peak flux density. A core by itself does not have a certain volt-second rating, you can wind more turns to it an it would take more volt-seconds.

Comment: @winny Please see my comment to Andy's answer in which I explain, why I believe that a core *does* indeed have saturation flux value based only on its magnetic properties. What is flawed in this argument?

Comment: I'm sorry tobalt but, you know the rules about widening the goalposts of a question after an answer has been given hence, I've rolled back your question to how it was originally stated.

Comment: @Andyaka I do not see that this edit does widen goalposts, it does not even invalidate your answer. If you disagree, flag it for moderator judgement.

Comment: I have flagged it. Basically, the reason for the flag is that I suspect that you expect any newer answer to justify the reasons behind the maths in your modification. This isn't the way to do things here and you've been around long enough to know that.

Comment: @Andyaka my version of this is: My edit merely pours the argument that has already been there, into mathematical terms. It is the same argument, that I explained in the first comment to your answer.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't see how the minor edit to the question is "widening the goalposts". It does not seem to have invalidated your answer since the part of the question you quoted did not change.

Comment: @Null the added sentence is an incorrect assertion and, because I had already answered his unmodified question, I didn't want to go to all the trouble of re-educating the OP to show him that his added words were incorrect. If he'd taken the time to understand what I was saying after I made the roll-back he wouldn't have reinstated those incorrect words. In short I was also doing him a favour. [Why doesn't the cross section of a material affect flux density?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/687911/why-doesnt-the-cross-section-of-a-material-affect-flux-density/687930#687930)

Comment: In other words it's a classic case of inappropriate question modification after an answer is given.

Comment: @Andyaka If you don't want to "go to all the trouble" of expanding your answer then don't. The OP and other users will vote accordingly.

Comment: @Null you are missing the point.

Comment: @Andyaka moreover, my added sentence isn't an incorrect assertion. It is totally correct. The core *does* have a fixed saturation point given by B.A. irrespective of its winding properties. It's just that this *fixed* core Vs rating doesn't translate 1:1 to its windings.

Comment: @tobalt then your added part must be using a form of English I don't understand. I mean: *are both independent on its windings* <-- shouldn't you mean both **interdependent** on its windings. And anyway, core saturation is a material property that may or may not be produced by too much flux.

Comment: @Andyaka perhaps it's a bit sloppy - will edit. Both Bsat and A of the transformer core are independent o**f** its windings. Therefore Phi_sat has to be independent of its windings.

Comment: Sloppy isn't the word for it. Your added statement caused me to believe that you might be saying that B and A are independent and that, as I showed in the comment link above, is not true. I tried to do you a favour and all I seem to get back is abuse.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry for the misunderstanding based on a single-letter typo.

Comment: @Andyaka Regardless of whatever point you are trying to make, it was a legitimate edit to the question and you'll just need to deal with it as you see fit.

Comment: I think you should be able to see that the wording was incorrect to the point of it misleading me into what he was asking. Basically, turning it into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) in my opinion. Glorfindel also speaks of this succinctly: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286804/338419

Comment: @Andyaka The addition of one sentence does not make it a chameleon question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I disagree. The change made (as you can now see for yourself) was an erroneous one in that it had sufficient ambiguity (bad grammar) as to persuade me that he was making a false assertion. It's detailed above of course. False assertions need addressing too and, I chose to roll-back the question to how it was when I answered it. I wanted to search for the way of showing the assertion was wrong but the op was having none of it and, he immediately rolled-it forward to show the ambiguous assertion. Then I had no choice other than to flag the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The transformer/inductor core saturation parameter is not a Volt.Second product, though it is frequently pronounced like that, perhaps to save syllables, assuming a single turn. It is a Volts_Per_Turn.Second product.

If you have a winding with twice as many turns, you can apply twice as many volts.

Consider an inductor wound with two separate identical windings. The core flux does not care whether you connect these windings in parallel, to get V at twice the I, or in series, to get twice the V at only one I.

If you have some windings on a core, you can easily scale the core Vs/turn property by the actual number of turns on a particular winding, to give you a Vs product specific to that winding.

Comment: So when I apply 1 Vs to a winding, I don't actually cause 1 Vs of flux, but only 1 Vs/N (with N being number of turns in said winding) ? Ok this explains, why the winding-specific would not match the core's Vs saturation rating. Thank you!

Comment: To all other people who answered this (seemingly obvious ?) question: Perhaps, Neil's answer isn't the neatest, but it's what made me see where my confusion lied. I now recognize, that you all essentially brought up the same argument about Faraday's law of induction and the \$N\$ in it. So to future reader's of this question: Please read the other answers, too.

Comment: @tobalt I just dropped into this and see all the writing. I pulled [up these snips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ3W3.png) from some old document I'd written on designing an inductor for the Joule Thief. Anyway, I agree with you that Neil said it very well.

Answer (score 2):

> *Now I was confused, because the latter consideration would indicate
> that the Volt-Second saturation does in fact depend on the winding
> properties and is not a property of the core.*

Core permeability, current and number of turns dictate the saturation point. For convenience that can be equated to `volt.seconds` but, it will be a different value for a different number of turns.

We probably all know this: -

$$V = N\dfrac{d\Phi}{dt}$$

So, if we rearrange we get this:  -

$$V\cdot dt = N\cdot d\Phi$$

Or, `volt.seconds` yields flux multiplied by the number of turns.

Comment: When I add more turns, and thus increase the volt-second saturation point of the winding: How does this relate to the core having a *fixed* crosssectional area, *fixed* saturation flux density, and thus *fixed* saturation flux (which is the product of saturation flux density and crosssectional area), which can be also equated to a *fixed* volt-second saturation point of the *core* ? In this argument I am talking about the magnetic circuit only, and use Vs only as units for the flux. I am confused why they don't match the winding-specific Vs number.

Comment: I'm sorry but I answered your question i.e. your initial assumption about V.s being related only to the core is incorrect. In other words if you have a 2:1 step down transformer, the core will see the same flux when half the voltage is applied to the secondary

Comment: If you insist... In my opinion, you only re-stated the second side of my confusion. You did not indicate what is flawed with the argument that led me to the first side of my confusion.

Comment: You haven't provided an argument for V.s being a core property.

Comment: What? lol.. ok nvm then. If you do mind, re-read the second sentence of my question, or first comment to your answer.

Comment: I'm serious dude. My answer states the truth of the matter and, your pre-conceived thoughts that V.s is strictly a core property is incorrect.

Comment: I fully trust you that it is incorrect, but I don't understand which link in that argumentation chain is wrong.

Comment: @tobalt you said ths --> *I often find this value stated in Volt-Seconds, which is a unit for the saturation flux, i.e. the maximum flux that the core can hold.* <-- and, that only applies to both windings of a 1:1 transformer.

Comment: Your last edit is helpful. Please restrain from undoing my clarifications in the questions. They do not invalidate your answer.

Comment: @tobalt have you downvoted my answer?

Comment: Nope, as I said, I find it helpful, though not to the extent that it fully answers where my confusion originates.

Comment: Nobody but you can answer as to where your confusion originates.

Answer (score 2):

Correct, you need to know the winding reference.  Usually it's labeled "primary", but datasheets are often vague about this, and one may wish to ask the manufacturer.

There's also the matter of whether it's peak, peak-to-peak, sine wave, RMS, or what flux.  Peak should be the most common, but you never know unless specified.

Regarding the confusion between cores and windings, consider that there are two fluxes in play here: the free field flux \$B A_e\$, and the electrical or in-circuit flux \$B A_e N\$.  When I present calculations on these, I include a fake unit of "turns" (t) (usually arising from \$\mu_0\$ or \$A_e\$), to make it explicit that the field flux is per-turn, while the electrical flux is at given turns.  (Inserted on the proper constant, we automatically get \$A_L\$ in units of H/t<sup>2</sup>, for example.  Oh hm, it's both then isn't it? :) )

Alternately, one might carefully label the variables, like using capital \$\Phi\$ for field flux, and lowercase \$\phi = \Phi N\$ for circuit flux.

Comment: Not my downvote. Just for clarification: if the *apparent* in-circuit saturation flux is \$B\cdot A\cdot N\$, then that means, that applying 1 Vs to a winding of \$N\$ turns, only causes 1 Vs/N of flux in the core?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> I often find this value stated in Volt-Seconds

Volt-seconds i.e. flux, along with core properties including saturation flux **density**, becomes a transformer parameter. Volt-seconds also equals to Ampere-Henries.

$$
V_L \ \Delta t = L \ \Delta i
$$

So, for an inductor *(can also be a transformer's one of the windings)* with an inductance of L with a number of turns of N, by applying either of the following, you shouldn't exceed the Volt-seconds product which corresponds to, as you said, \$\Phi_{sat} = B_{sat} \ A_e\$:

- a voltage of **V** across the terminals, for a time duration of **Δt**, or
- a current change of **Δi**

> But then I thought about what happens in a 2:1 transformer when I apply the same Vs to one or the other winding

We can model a transformer like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyLUat.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

<sup>*I'll not explain what is what, as you already know.*</sup>

The above model shows that only the primary winding has a "magnetising" inductance which is a result of an assumption like "This winding will magnetise the core" *(The rest is an ideal transformer which has infinite magnetising inductance and therefore isn't mentioned)*. We often don't think about magnetisation using any other windings. As a result, when we design a transformer, after determining the turns ratio, we calculate the number of turns of the "primary" or "magnetising winding" using Faraday's equation:

$$
V_t = N \ A_e \ \frac{dB}{dt}
$$

So we define the Volt-seconds for primary (or whichever winding is assumed to be magnetising the core). So if you apply the same Volt-seconds to another winding, specifically to one having a lower number of turns, the flux swing will be higher and maybe closer to (or even beyond) the saturation level.

As a result, if we define Volt-seconds for a transformer, we should also define its "primary winding". Or in other words, **Volt-seconds per turn**. We don't often use the latter because we know that one specific winding will be used as a primary i.e. the winding that magnetises the core.

Also, as I mentioned above as `Ampere-Henries`, if you apply the same Volt-seconds to a lower inductance (which is a result of a lower number of turns) you'll cause a larger current change which in turn will cause a higher H-field change. Because of the relation between B and H, the B swing will be higher and closer to the saturation point.

Comment: Aha! So is it, that applying Vs to an actual winding, we *also* cause a current. And this current times inductance adds additional flux to the "pure" volt-second flux ?

Comment: @tobalt sorry, my answer was unfinished, I accidentally posted. Wait for the update.

Comment: @tobalt Please see the edit.